# How to remove alphabetic values from String and how to get desired String like in description?

Tags: java, android, regex, string

I have the following string:

```
   String textString = "Value for CH2 234 45  HH 2546";
```

I need a regex to remove white spaces between numbers but also want to avoid if there is a non-numeric value before a number like

```
String texString="23445 2546";
```

Here want to avoid the numerical value after any non-numeric value Here in my String want to avoid the numeric value also after H there are 2 but I just want to make a string like "23445 2546". if there is any alphabetic character is there it should be removed and add the whitespace between numbers.

```
 static String getNumber(String textString) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("(?<!\\w)\\d+(?!\\w)").matcher(textString);
    while (matcher.find()) {
        sb.append(matcher.group());
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

From Above regex and code i am getting output:

```
    String texString="234452546";
```

Required output:

```
    String texString="23445 2546";
```

Update:

If there is String like

```
       String textString = "Value for CH2 234 45  HH 25.46";
```

output:
String texString="23445 2546";

Required output:

```
        String texString="23445 25.46";

enter code here
```

Comment: Why would it be "23445 2546" and not "234 45 2546" preserving all the spaces?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use this regex for your matches:

```sh
\b\d[\d.]*\b(?:\h(?!\h*\d))?
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/ZtozuS/3)

**RegEx Explanation:**

- `\b`: Word boundary
- `\d`: Match 1 digit
- `[\d.]*`: Match 0 or more digits or dot
- `\b`: Word boundary
- `(?:`: Start *optional* non-capture group

  - `\h`: Match a horizontal whitespace
  - `(?!\h*\d)`: Negative lookahead to assert that we don't have a digit ahead after matching 0 or more whitespaces
- `)?`: End *optional* non-capture group

**Code:**

```sh
String textString = "Value for CH2 234 45  HH 25.46";
final String re = "\\b\\d[\\d.]*\\b(?:\\h(?!\\h*\\d))?";
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile(re).matcher(textString);
while (matcher.find()) {
    sb.append(matcher.group());
}
System.out.println(sb.toString());
```

**Output:**

```
23445 25.46
```

---

**Java code using Java 9+ `.results()` method:**

```sh
final String re = "\\b\\d[\\d.]*\\b(?:\\h(?!\\h*\\d))?";
String out = Pattern.compile(re)
            .matcher(textString)
            .results()
            .map(MatchResult::group)
            .collect(Collectors.joining());

System.out.println(out);
```

Comment: Yah its worked for me but its also remove the '.' i want to include . between numbers.

Comment: Can you edit your question and show updated examples with expected output.

Comment: @NitinThakor -Try `\b[.\d]+(?:\h(?!\h*\d))?`